# Lamina Batched Queue

Tags: clojure, channel, lamina-clojure

I'm trying to write a web service that takes requests, puts them into a queue, and then processes them in batches of 2.  The response can be sent straight away, and I'm trying to use Lamina as follows (though not sure it's the right choice)...

```
(def ch (channel))

(def loop-forever
  (comp doall repeatedly))

(defn consumer []
  (loop-forever
    (fn []
      (process-batch
        @(read-channel ch)
        @(read-channel ch)))))

(def handler [req]
  (enqueue ch req)
  {:status 200
   :body "ok"})
```

But this doesn't work...  :(  I've been through all the Lamina docs but can't get my head around how to use these channels.  Can anyone confirm if Lamina supports this kind of behaviour and advise on a possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of lamina is that you don't want to loop forever: you want lamina's scheduler to use a thread from its pool to do work for you whenever you have enough data to do work on. So instead of using the very, very low-level `read-channel` function, use `receive` to register a callback once, or (more often) `receive-all` to register a callback for every time a channel receives data. For example:

```
(def ch (lamina/channel))

(lamina/receive-all (lamina/partition* 2 channel)
                    (partial apply process-batch))

(defn handler [req]
  (lamina/enqueue ch req)
  {:status 200
   :body "ok"})
```